# camera calibration

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

When I try to calibrate microsoft lifecam using the tutorials in the below link :

http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration

I got the values. However if I need to convert to ros understandable yaml file, I need to fill in the distortion model and the camera model. I saw an example for prosilica but do not know what to fill in for the lifecam.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Best Regards
Praveen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78236/camera-calibration/) by [RamAlien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2451/ramalien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure I understand your problem (because you can find the link also on http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration), but I'm thinking you need this: http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration_parsers

example for a .ini file (kinect camera):

```
# oST version 5.0 parameters


[image]

width
1280

height
1024

[narrow_stereo/left]

camera matrix
1429.274851 0.000000 642.481927
0.000000 1430.114034 493.656022
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

distortion
0.203354 -0.626886 0.002481 0.000232 0.000000

rectification
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

projection
1450.860596 0.000000 642.215646 0.000000
0.000000 1452.523071 494.611373 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
```

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1